# In VB how do you display all strings in an array on a timer?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, timer

Ok, here's my use case. I have a form that pulls different parts of the form from a number of tables in a database. Each time I pull the info, I test to make sure there were no errors. Currently I'm using msgbox to show if there are errors, but I'm rewriting the app to instead display these messages in a "status" line area. It's just a label that I write the strings into on the form that flashes the error. This is working great in my single "You did this, and you got an error" forms. But in one of my forms it's about 6 things that could give errors, and it's on load. So it's not a single action, single error type deal.

My idea is to load any errors into an array, then display them one at a time for like 5 seconds each, then loop back and do it again, for at least 5 times. So in effect I want it to show each error, for 5 seconds, then show the next one for 5 seconds, then start over again, for 5 times, then stop.

Problem is, while I've got about 10 ideas on ways to maybe do this, they all seem really complicated and complex (and I don't want to spend 10 hours writing it only to figure out it's not going to work). I'm looking for the "best" way.

So.... Is an array even the best way? Or would a list or some other way be better? I'm looking for ideas here. How would YOU do it?

Comment: Write them out to a log file, then pull them as needed and display them however you wish. Not only that you now have a physical file you can look back at and get what you need...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, you can use arrays for what you are trying to achieve. This could be done by following the steps :

1. When you are pulling the information from the tables, check for errors and if there is any, put it into an array.
2. Define a for loop which is going to loop 5 times
3. Define another nested loop to loop through the array to display the messages one by one
4. After each message display, put a sleep or delay of 5 seconds

If you follow these instructions, it just a matter of minutes into writing the codes

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using a combobox and a list, then just having my combobox blink. On forms that can only throw one error, I use a label instead. Here is the lion's share of my code to do this:

```
 Private Sub ErrorCheck()

    If errorList.Count = 1 Then
        ErrorComboBox.Visible = True
        DismissErrorButton.Visible = True
        For Each errors As String In errorList
            ErrorComboBox.Text = (errors)
        Next
        ErrorBlinkTimer.Enabled = True            
    ElseIf errorList.Count > 1 Then
        ErrorComboBox.Visible = True
        DismissErrorButton.Visible = True
        ErrorComboBox.Text = "There were errors, click drop down to view!"
        For Each errors As String In errorList
            ErrorComboBox.Items.Add(errors)
        Next
    Else

    End If


End Sub
```

What I do is after each thing in a SUB that can throw errors, I have it collect the error and write it to errorList with errorList.add like so:

```
 Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errorStr = "An Error Occurred in " & Me.Name & " writing into the OpenEvents table " _
                           & "for setting the Alert radio button."
        log(errorStr & " - " & ex.Message)
        errorList.Add(errorStr)
```

the log function is a custom function for writing off to the log, but the rest is standard VB.net stuff. As you can see, if I get any exception (I do the same thing with each query too) it writes the error off to the errorList, then flashes the combobox with the error(s). I have some more logic to make it all nice and pretty, but you get the idea.

at the end of each sub that CAN throw errors, I just have it call:

```
ErrorCheck()
```

and like magic, if there were any errors a combobox list appears with bright red flashing text to let them know. If they click it, and there is more than one error, they can see them all in a nice list. Clicking it also makes it stop flashing, cause that would be annoying... LOL

This ended up working much better overall really, but it's not quite as pretty as my first way of doing it... but, no matter what I did, it caused issues on the form(s) to have it running through the flashing loop 5x's to display each error one after the other. I had found work arounds for most of it, but there was still a performance impact, so I dumped it for this. And it does the job well enough.